# Problems with inline assembly in visual studio c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I'm new to assembly and I decided to implement some simple functions for graphs using the inline assembly, I started with the constructor which is supposed to initialise all elements of the adjacency matrix to 0, but I don't understand what I did wrong

```
struct graph {
int el[MAX_V][MAX_V];
int noVert;
int noEdges;
bool directed;

graph() {
    _asm {

    mov     ebx, 0
    mov     esi, MAX_V
    mov     edi, this
START_L1:
    cmp     ebx, MAX_V
    je      END_L1

    mov     ecx, 0
    START_L2:
    cmp     ecx, MAX_V
    je      END_L2

    mov     eax, ebx
    imul    esi
    add     eax, ecx
    mov     [edi + eax*4], dword ptr 0

    inc     ecx
    jmp     START_L2;
    END_L2:

    inc     ebx
    jmp     START_L1
END_L1:

    }
}
}
```

When I use the debugger I find that the int element of the `el` array that I'm updating contains a non zero value after this instruction is executed:

```
mov     [edi + eax*4], dword ptr 0
```

Why am I getting non-zero int value placed in the `el` array after this instruction? I'm expecting the integer at the index I am updating to be set to zero.

Comment: So, [it doesn't work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616/333362)?

Comment: it doesn't work , in debugger it replaces some parts of the memory with some random variables and that's it

Comment: What is it supposed to do? Please post enough information to replicate the problem. Something I could copy and paste into visual studio, compile and debug with details of what you expect and what you got would make this question easier to answer.

Comment: " I started with the constructor which is supposed to initialise all elements of the adjacency matrix to 0"

Comment: You should be aware that this is about 100 times *less efficient* than what the compiler would generate if you wrote the code in C++. If you are just trying to learn assembly language programming, inline assembly is a terrible way to do it. You should write the assembly by hand, not inline in a C++ program. Visual Studio comes with MASM, which is Microsoft's assembler that you can use to write assembly language programs directly.

Comment: @MichaelPetch thanks it worked

Comment: @orenrevenge : If the information provided helped would you consider accepting an answer so this question can be marked as solved? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

When using Microsoft's Intel syntax with a `dword ptr` qualifier you should specify the size on the memory operand and not the immediate value.

This line is a problem:

```
mov     [edi + eax*4], dword ptr 0
```

Although you specify `dword ptr` on the immediate value `0` the Microsoft compiler/assembler will realize that `0` can fit in a byte and will emit the instruction as:

```
mov     byte ptr [edi+eax*4], 0
```

What you really want to do is tell the compiler/assembler that the size of the item in the memory operand is a 32-bit DWORD. To do that modify the instruction to be:

```
mov     dword ptr [edi + eax*4], 0
```

The reason your code appeared to have garbage in the array is because only the least significant byte of each array element was set to 0.

---

Unless this was an assignment that asked you to code this way, you really should use *C++* code to zero out the array. It will also make this code more maintainable and readable. The compiler should be able to generate efficient code to do the zeroing if a reasonable optimization level is used.